# one f.select is affecting another within the same form? (unwanted)

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a problem where, when adding a new html element such as:

```
<%= f.date_select :date, { id: "date-select"} %>
```

it affects my already existing collection select:

```
<%= f.collection_select :id,
                          Customer.where(business_id: current_customer.business_id),
                          :id,
                          :full_name,
                          { prompt: 'Select' },
                          { id: "colleague-select", onChange: "renderColCal(this)" } %>
```

Usually, the customer can select another customer from the list, triggering an ajax call to render the selected customer's calendar using the selected customer's `id`. This works fine by itself.

However, when I put in this new `date_select` option further up in the form, and then try to use the `collection_select`, the ajax call can't be finished because it is trying to find a customer with an `id` equal to the year of the date that's been selected in the other select box!!

Here is an example. I have selected a date with the year "2012" in my `date_select`. Then I select a customer in the `collection_select` and receive this in the console:

```
Started GET "/calendars/calendar_change?colleagueID=2012" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-01 11:38:01 +0000
Processing by CalendarsController#calendar_change as */*
  Parameters: {"colleagueID"=>"2012"}
  Customer Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "customers".* FROM "customers"  WHERE "customers"."id" = ?  ORDER BY last_name ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2012]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 5ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Customer with 'id'=2012):
  app/controllers/calendars_controller.rb:19:in `calendar_change'
```

this is my javascript being called:

```
function renderColCal(select){

    var colleagueID = select.value ;
    $.ajax({
            url: '/calendars/calendar_change',
            data:{
                colleagueID: $('select').val()
            }
        }
    )
```

}

Why is this happening? How do I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your javascript. The data you are submitting is

```
data:{
   colleagueID: $('select').val()
}
```

which submit the value of the first select on the page. If you want to go that route, you'd have to make the selector you've passed to $() more selective (for example, using the id of the select box).

You are actually retrieving the value from the select box earlier in your event handler, but you're not using it for some reason. This is probably less error prone than using jquery to find the select element when it is already being passed to you.